# Reading CSV files located on LINUX server and updating the tables in SQL Server Database

Tags: linux, sql-server-2008-r2, redhat

I was wondering how do we ingest CSV files located on a Red Hat LINUX server into SQL Server Database Table.

I know we can write a Stored Procedure/Bulk Insert to read the files that are located on the same Windows Server as SQL Server and update the database but not sure how to do it when the files are present in LINUX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to proceed once the csv file is on your Windows box, it seems this question amounts to how to get the file from a Linux server to a Windows server. I suggest rcp or rsync. There are Windows versions of both.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there is a way to mount Windows Drive on LINUX so that the files can be shared across that way

Comment: You can run an NFS client on Windows and mount it on Linux. You can also go the opposite way and mount the Linux drive on Windows using Samba.